# Additional packages to use with NodaTime

Tags: nodatime

I am updating an application to use [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) to fix many existing time issues with our data and processes.

I will need to resolve timezones from a mobile app that sends IANA timezone names. I will need to support conversions to UTC using custom offsets (i.e. hard coded -04:00). I may or may not need to support Windows timezone names as well.

For all of this, I am wondering if I need additional packages. How do [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) and [TimeZoneNames](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneNames) work alongside NodaTime? Are there any other additional packages I should use alongside NodaTime?

Our ultimate goal is to get all data persisted as Utc and convert to/from user time only for display or accepting user input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any extra packages for that scenario, as far as I can see.

- For IANA IDs, just use `DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb`
- For "raw offset" IDs, you can use any time zone provider, asking for an ID of the form "UTC+01:00" etc. (So you'd need to add the "UTC" prefix.)
- For Windows zone mapping, you can use `TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default` to get the default TZDB information, then use the [`WindowsMapping`](https://nodatime.org/2.4.x/api/NodaTime.TimeZones.TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.html#NodaTime_TimeZones_TzdbDateTimeZoneSource_WindowsMapping) property to get a `WindowsZones` object you can use for mapping.

`TimeZoneConverter` may well be simpler to use for the last bullet point, but it's not required. The IANA IDs it provides *should* work fine with Noda Time.

`TimeZoneNames` is more about displaying time zone names to users. If you don't need to do that, you probably don't need the package.

Note that persisting all data as UTC *may* be a really bad idea - it's hard to tell without knowing more about your application. If you only deal with values in the past, or if they're fixed instants in time, that's fine. But if you're allowing users to schedule future events, I'd store the values that the user gave you. Here's an example of why...

Suppose the user says they want to schedule an event for Europe/Paris at 9am on December 1st 2021. If you convert that to UTC *now*, you'll end up with 2021-12-01T08:00Z, because the current time zone rules say that Paris will be at UTC+1 in December 2021.

However, it's entirely possible that between now and 2021, France will have changed its time zone rules to be on "permanent daylight time", i.e. UTC+2 all year round. At that point, your UTC value of 2021-12-01T08:00Z would correspond to 10am in Paris on the given date - contrary to what the user specified.

It's fine to convert to UTC *as well* so that you can create a totally ordered view of the data, so long as you retain enough information to perform that conversion again every time there's new time zone data.

As I say, that may not be an issue for you, but it's worth knowing that the "received wisdom" of "Always store everything in UTC" is really not good advice for *all* scenarios.

Comment: Thank you for the information, and thank you very much for the advice about Utc storage. We have many dates in use, including an appointment book implementation that will absolutely have the future dates issue you point out.